# Perl Prerequisites on Local Install

Tags: perl

I am simply trying to install some Perl modules.  I install Spiffy-0.30 into my local directory using

```
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=~/lib LIB=~/lib
```

and that works fine.  Then I try to install Test-Base-6.0 which Spiffy is a prerequisite using the same code and it states I am missing Spiffy.  Is there a way to instruct Perl on what directory to look for the prerequisites??

Comment: I assume that if `~/lib` is in your `PERL5LIB` path, Perl will be able to find it when installing other modules. Give that a shot.

Comment: No ~/lib is a directory I created, I need it to install in a directory I create so I can include it with my scripts.

Comment: Exactly. Since you created it, you need to tell Perl where it is. I think the `PERL5LIB` environmental variable will do just that.

Comment: Adding to the make file : use lib 'path-to-lib';  Did it, thanks for the info.  If you want to type it as an answer I can give you the points.

Comment: Using the approach I described in my answer will make it so you don't have to modify the makefile for each new module you download. You will also need `~/lib` in your `PERL5LIB` path at runtime, not just installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `~lib` is not the default location for Perl modules, you need to tell Perl where to find it. You can do that with the `PERL5LIB` environmental variable. Here is the terminal output from my Ubuntu box.

```
standage@ubuntu:~$ mkdir ~/lib
standage@ubuntu:~$ tar xzf Spiffy-0.30.tar.gz
standage@ubuntu:~$ cd Spiffy-0.30/
standage@ubuntu:~/Spiffy-0.30$ perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=~/lib LIB=~/lib
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Spiffy
standage@ubuntu:~/Spiffy-0.30$ make
cp lib/Spiffy.pm blib/lib/Spiffy.pm
Manifying blib/man3/Spiffy.3pm
standage@ubuntu:~/Spiffy-0.30$ make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/autoload.t .. ok   
t/base.t ...... ok     
t/base2.t ..... ok   
t/cascade.t ... ok     
t/const.t ..... ok   
t/early.t ..... ok   
t/export1.t ... ok     
t/export2.t ... ok   
t/export3.t ... ok   
t/export4.t ... ok     
t/export5.t ... ok   
t/export6.t ... ok   
t/export7.t ... ok   
t/exporter.t .. ok   
t/field.t ..... ok   
t/field2.t .... ok   
t/field3.t .... ok   
t/filter.t .... ok   
t/filter2.t ... ok   
t/filter3.t ... ok   
t/filter4.t ... ok   
t/filter5.t ... ok   
t/mixin.t ..... ok     
t/mixin2.t .... ok     
t/mixin3.t .... ok   
t/new.t ....... ok   
t/package.t ... ok   
t/parse.t ..... ok   
t/stub.t ...... ok   
t/super.t ..... ok   
t/super2.t .... ok   
All tests successful.
Files=31, Tests=198,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.19 usr  0.30 sys +  0.88 cusr  0.48 csys =  1.85 CPU)
Result: PASS
standage@ubuntu:~/Spiffy-0.30$ make install
Installing /home/standage/lib/Spiffy.pm
Installing /home/standage/lib/man/man3/Spiffy.3pm
Appending installation info to /home/standage/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/perllocal.pod
standage@ubuntu:~/Spiffy-0.30$ cd ..
standage@ubuntu:~$ tar xzf Test-Base-0.60.tar.gz 
standage@ubuntu:~$ cd Test-Base-0.60/
standage@ubuntu:~/Test-Base-0.60$ perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=~/lib LIB=~/lib
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Spiffy 0.30 not found.
Writing Makefile for Test::Base
standage@ubuntu:~/Test-Base-0.60$ export PERL5LIB=~/lib:$PERL5LIB
standage@ubuntu:~/Test-Base-0.60$ perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=~/lib LIB=~/lib
Writing Makefile for Test::Base
standage@ubuntu:~/Test-Base-0.60$
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to install modules locally, may I suggest the [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/module/local%3a%3alib) module? It takes the headache out of most of this.